# How do you close an <iframe> from inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a web page, room.html, with table onclick = function place():

```
function place()                
var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
x.setAttribute("src", "loading.html");
document.body.appendChild(x);
                }
```

How do we close the iframe with a button in the page loading.html?

Comment: Explain "close". But anyway, do you really want an *iframe* with external loaing.html to show loading indicator?

Comment: it's not an iframe for loading indicator and close mean close

Answer (score 0):

you can just remove it directly using jQuery

```
$('iframe').remove();
```

Comment: In button onclick function.

Comment: $( "#buttonId" ).click(function() {
  $('iframe').remove();
});

Comment: just replace the buttonId with your button Id on the html

Comment: I did not want for myself. I asked for the person who asked the question.  So just update your answer(Edit). @HaithamQaffesha